# Mimic Dock view in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview

In my app I want to mimic the dock as displayed in Mac.Instead of using tab bar I want to use a dock kind of view in my app so that when a user taps on a dock item a new view is displayed.Is there any code or help availble for the same?

Comment: I'm not aware of any code to do it, but there's a decent chance that app would not be allowed in the app store.  There was a "dashboard" like app a while back and the reason for it being banned was that the interface was too computer like.

Comment: This question is terribly general. It's almost like asking "How does the Cocoa view and controller hierarchy work?". It would be better if you did a little work to break the question down into parts, so we know what you already know and what you need. Do you know how to use a UIControl? Do you know how to switch between UIViewControllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use photoshop to create the dock graphic, and individual buttons. upon one of the buttons being pressed have a new view transition in.  Apple has sample code of how to transition views in their iPhone sample code.